# Program Crashing after map update

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am a beginner to web development and developing a program where I update the map by an ajax call using leaflet and it works fine.Now I update the map every 10 seconds So my function to update the map is below:

```
 function update_the_map(){                 
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        async : false,
                        url: 'http://backendserver:port/update, 
                        success: function(data) {
                            var n=0;
                            for (j = 0; j<3000; j++) { 


                                if(linestring['features'][j]['properties']['color']!=data[j].color){
                                      linestring['features'][j]['properties']['color']=data[j].color;
                                }   

                            }

                    if (vectorGrid) {

                        vectorGrid.remove(); 
                                console.log("removed the previous layer");

                            }

                            var vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(linestring, {
                                rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                                vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                                    sliced: function(properties, zoom) {

                                        return {

                                            weight: 2,
                                            opacity: 1,

                                            color: getColor(properties.color),


                                            fillOpacity: 0.7
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                interactive: true,
                                getFeatureId: function(f) {
                                    return f.properties.id;
                                }
                            })




                            .addTo(map);                            

                            console.log("updated the new layer");

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                            alert(thrownError);
                          },
                        complete: function() {
                         if(time){
                             clearTimeout(time);

                         }

                         time= setTimeout(update_the_map, 10000);
                        }
                      });

            }
```

Then I call the function in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = mapupdatecolor();

</script>
```

But this works fine for some time then the error shows that the browser has no memory.So when I looked into the same kinda error I think it should be something wrong with the timeout function. But could not exactly find where the error occurs.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please copy / paste the JS error?

Comment: Actually it is not a JS error.it is that OS kills the browser process. `AW Snap! Google chrome ran out of memory while trying to display web page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your code. The only reason why the browser can run out of memory seems to be the instantiation of `L.vectorGrid.slicer`.

You should try to free the memory used by the instance you remove before creating a new instance.

It will probably not be enough but you could do this just after `vectorGrid.remove();` :

```
delete vectorGrid;
```

If it does not fix your problem. Look for a way to clean everything that was created by the vectorGrid.

**UPDATE :**

I just noticed your `vectorGrid` variable is re-declared in each ajax success function call and is local to one call. This might also be the cause of the memory leak. The garbage collector might be thinking this local variable is never useless so it does not "free" the memory.

Here is what you could try :

```
// HERE IS A CHANGE
var vectorGrid;

function update_the_map(){                 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async : false,
        url: 'http://backendserver:port/update', 
        success: function(data) {
            var n=0;
            for (j = 0; j<3000; j++) { 
                if(linestring['features'][j]['properties']['color']!=data[j].color){
                    linestring['features'][j]['properties']['color']=data[j].color;
                }   
            }

            if (vectorGrid) {
                vectorGrid.remove();
                // HERE IS A CHANGE 
                vectorGrid = undefined;
                console.log("removed the previous layer");
            }

            // HERE IS A CHANGE
            vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(linestring, {
                rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                    sliced: function(properties, zoom) {

                        return {

                            weight: 2,
                            opacity: 1,

                            color: getColor(properties.color),


                            fillOpacity: 0.7
                        }
                    }
                },
                interactive: true,
                getFeatureId: function(f) {
                    return f.properties.id;
                }
            })




                .addTo(map);                            

            console.log("updated the new layer");

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            alert(thrownError);
        },
        complete: function() {
            if(time){
                clearTimeout(time);
            }
            time= setTimeout(update_the_map, 10000);
        }
    });

}
```

This way there is just one `vectorGrid` variable which content is potentially freed on each `update_the_map` call.

Comment: It still crashes after keeping `delete vectorGrid;` . What do u mean by clean everything that was created by the vectorGrid?

Comment: It means free the memory used by vectorGrid instance. The goal is to prevent the crash by keeping the memory usage reasonably low.

Comment: I tried your above changes in the program but still it crashes. What may be the reason?

Comment: The reason is clear : memory usage grows until the browser crashes. Maybe the cause is vectorGrid plugin that waste memory or does not clean it when an instance is "removed" from the map.